Area of a cardioid and a circle
Given the Cardioid by $f(\varphi)=3-3\cos(\varphi)$ and the circle given by $g(\varphi)=-6\cos(\varphi)$. I have 2 questions regarding its areas:

Why $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}g(\varphi)^2d\varphi=9\pi$ when it should be $\frac{9\pi}{2}$?
Why $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}g(\varphi)^2 - f(\varphi)^2d\varphi=\frac{-9\pi}{4}$ when it should be $\frac{9\pi}{4}$?

The first question regards the area of a circle of diameter $6$ and the second questions is about how much more area has the Cardioid than the circle. About how I know that the results should be those: The circle has diameter $6$ so it's area is $9\pi$ and hence the integral of the first halve of the circle in polar coordinates should be $\frac{9\pi}{2}$. About the other result, if I calculate $\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}g(\varphi)^2$ and substract the half area of the circle it gives $\frac{9\pi}{4}$.

If you plot the two curves, you will easily see that the cardioid encircles a bigger area than the circle

Please provide an explicit calculation that leads you to claim "it should be $\frac{9\pi}2$".

@Lieven Hope that helps

It's not the first half of the circle but the full circle. The origin lies on the circumference, not at the centre. All of the circle lies between the polar arguments $0$ and $\pi.$
